# Why was Reddington looking for the girl?

Tags: character, the-blacklist

Over the course of the first season of *The Blacklist*, we see Reddington looking for clues about a girl whom we may assume to be his daughter. Most notably, we see him remove one photograph from the book of victims of the Stewmaker (S1E4). Berlin turns out to have the same photograph in his pocket watch.

[image: photograph in Berlin's pocket watch]
[image: photograph Reddington took from The Stewmaker]

But in the season one finale, only *then* Reddington seems to learn that the girls is Berlin's daughter and that Berlin is after Red for what he supposedly did to Berlin's daughter. It seems as if Reddington has no idea about Berlin nor his daughter before that.

**So why was he looking for her?**

Comment: Well I think the thing to keep in mind with Red is that even when he "doesn't know anything" that does not mean he know nothing at all. I think he had heard enough about the bad story of Berlin to track down the daughter but not *who he actually was*. All Berlin was, was a threat and a code name Berlin. Not much to go on when you are trying to find someone. So yeah "nothing" means something a little different to Red than to us normal people. :)

Comment: Subquestion: how did Berlin get another copy of what seems to be a Polaroid?

Answer (score -1):

The girl Reddington was looking for is [Luck Brooks](https://the-blacklist.wikia.com/wiki/Lucy_Brooks) (aka Jolene Parker). This girl is different from Berlin's daughter.

Presumably, Reddington has met this girl before and knows that this girl is working for his mysterious enemy. As such, he wished to find her to figure out who Berlin is.

Comment: That does not explain the photograph Reddington took from the Stewmaker's collection being the same as the one in Berlin's pocket watch.

Comment: They are not supposed to be.

Comment: [Yet they are](https://mikecanex.files.wordpress.com/2014/05/blacklistberlinredgirl79.jpg).

Comment: They very clearly are not only of the same girl, but are the same picture of the girl (which I'd bet is purely so the audience easily identified that this is the same girl)